# Need Guidance for deploying Huggingface model with Flask on Kubernetes with Ingress and GPU support

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flask, huggingface, mlops

So, I have developed a **chatbot based application** using multiple services (used multiple NodeJs servers + flask servers) dockerize and deployed as kubernetes pod and used minikube Ingress-Nginx Controller. The problem I am facing is that my Chatbot service requires **GPU support** which I am unable to provide with minikube. Is there any way or approach through which I can use GPU for services and which requires minimum changes in my current architecture...

Here, is the better explanation of my current architecture...

1. Client - React Service with Server side rendering
2. Auth Service - for authentication and creating session. It's NodeJs app service..
3. Profanity Service - Santitize Data.. Flask App and no need for GPU here...
4. Communication Service - Store Data and Responses and handles Communication with different services - NodeJs app service
5. Chatbot Service - Huggingface LLM Model with Flask App. For Generating response. Here, I required to use GPU...

Note: All services are deployed as Kubernetes pod in my local minikube with Ingress-Nginx Controller...

[image]

Comment: Why are you unable to provide GPU to the pod? OS issue or something else?

Comment: I am not able to access GPU inside the pod